# A que hace referencia 'this' en una Arrow Function? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, this

Estoy tratando de entender a que hace referencia la palabra clave 'this' en un arrow function de JavaScript pero la verdad no logro entenderlo. En palabras sencillas ¿a que hace referencia el this en un arrow function?

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código:

```
const persona = {
  nombre: "Juan",
  edad: 35,
  altura: 1.78,
  mostrarDatos: () => `Me llamo ${this.nombre} tengo ${this.edad} y mido ${this.altura}`
}
console.log(persona.mostrarDatos()); // Imprime undefined en las variables
```

Mientras que si lo pongo de esta otra manera, si hace referencia al objeto

```
const persona = {
  nombre: "Juan",
  edad: 35,
  altura: 1.78,
  mostrarDatos: function() {
    const mostrar = () => console.log(`Me llamo ${this.nombre} tengo ${this.edad} años y mido ${this.altura}`)
     mostrar();
  }
}
persona.mostrarDatos();
```

Entonces a que hace referencia?

Comment: En el primer caso, el scope de `persona` es el window, con lo cual intentará buscar la variable `window.nombre`. En el segundo caso, el padre de tu arrow function es una función, y el padre de esa función es el objeto `persona`, por eso ahí si funciona. Es decir, el `this` siempre será el `scope` del padre de la arrow function... resumido: this en una función de flecha, es el padre del padre de la función. He intentado simplificarlo todo lo que puedo, intentando no liarme en el proceso!

Comment: Lo que dice @Benito-B x2, igual considera aportar una respuesta

Comment: Si te entiendes con el inglés, te recomiendo leer [este artículo de codementor](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc) donde lo explica bastante mejor que yo.

Comment: Gracias a los que respondieron, ya lo logré entender :)

Answer (score 0):

El `this` en un `arrow function` hace referencia a la ventana global `window`, es decir si definimos una variable **nombre** en la ventana global, encontrará la referencia.

Ejemplo:

```
window.nombre = 'Juan';
window.edad = 23;
// no definimos altura en window    

const persona = {
nombre: "Juan",
edad: 35,
altura: 1.78,
mostrarDatos: () => `Me llamo ${this.nombre} tengo ${this.edad} y mido ${this.altura}`
}
console.log(persona.mostrarDatos()); // Imprime undefined en las variables
```

Verás que en este ejemplo la variable **altura** no esta definida en `window` y como el `this` en el `arrow function` se dirige a la ventana global `window`, la variable **altura** sale no definida.
Entonces el **this.nombre** y el **this.edad** ya tienen valores definidos, pero no son los valores **nombre** y **edad** del objeto persona.

Recuerda que los `arrow functions` a pesar de que nos ayudan a reducir el código, también tiene incorporado sus diferencias.

Más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Buena suerte.